# Cant build .kv file using kivy.lang.Builder. Shows Attribute error

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager,Screen

kv=Builder.load_file('my.kv')
class first(Screen):
    pass
class second(Screen):
    pass
class windowmanager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class myapp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv
    
if __name__=="__main__":
    myapp().run()
```

> [WARNING] [Lang        ] The file C:\Users\Jawahar\Documents\ml
> internship\my.kv is loaded multiples times, you might have unwanted
> behaviors. Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
> kv=Builder.load_file('my.kv')
>
> File
> "C:\Users\Jawahar\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py",
> line 301, in load_file
> return self.load_string(data, **kwargs)
>
> File
> "C:\Users\Jawahar\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py",
> line 399, in load_string
> widget = Factory.get(parser.root.name)(__no_builder=True)
>
> File
> "C:\Users\Jawahar\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\factory.py",
> line 130, in **getattr**
> raise AttributeError
>
> AttributeError

#kv file

```
windowmanager:
    first:
    second:

<first>:
    name:'first'

    Button:
        text:'press me'
        size_hint:(0.1,0.1)
        pos_hint:{'top':0.5,'right':0.5}
        color:(0.1,0.2,1,1)
<second>:
    name:'second'

    Button:
        text:'press me'
        size_hint:(0.1,0.1)
        pos_hint:{'top':0.5,'right':0.5}
        color:(0.1,0.2,1,1)
```

Comment: can you post your .kv file?

Comment: individually every window works. But collectively when loading file it fails.

Comment: You are trying to load the kv file before defining the `windowmanager` class, therefore when it tries to instantiate it the load fails. Also, use CamelCase for class names, sometimes that matters in kv.